# How to use the pushReplacement in onWillPop method

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Instead of popping the previous route I'm trying to **navigate to a new route** when user **presses the back button**.

think I'm in the `route1()` and push to the `route2()`. now I want to push to the `route3()` when the user presses the back button. and in the `route3()` when he/she press the back button again he get to `route1()`.

What I'm doing right now is that I use the `WillPopScope()` in `route2()` and when the user presses the back button in android i call the `pushReplacement()`. but when I get to `route3()` and press the back button I get to the `route2()`.

Answer (score 0):

When on `route1()`, try pushing `route3()` and immediatly after that puse `route2()`. This way `route2()` will be on top of the stack, and when the back button is pressed `route3()` will replace it with `route1()` right below it.